# Decision split - Marketing cloud

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, journey

I am experiencing problems with Decision Split evaluation in the Journey

Hello,
I configured the decision split as "Colour is not equal Red" AND "City equal Rome". The only record I have in the DE has the field Colour blank and the field City populated with Rome. If I activate the journey, the record follows the remainder path. It seems that not equal is different from null. Should I specify in the decision split?